# How to get the images from gallery or camera and crop with high quality in android

Tags: android, image, android-camera-intent

Hi I have to set profile image for my app. I have done to take images from gallery and camera and then crop it for perfect shape and displaying in my image view, But it is in low quality pixels the images are not clear. 
How to get the same quality as per the camera capture or images in gallery

My code is:

```
public class ProfileActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView iv_dp;

    boolean checkpermission ;
    File file;
    Uri uri;
    Intent CamIntent, GalIntent, CropIntent ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_activity);


        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        allowpermission();
       /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        1);

                checkpermission = true;
            }*/


            iv_dp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dp_iv);

            iv_dp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this);

                        alertbox.setTitle("Select an option")
                                .setItems(R.array.alert, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {

//pos will give the selected item position

                                        if (pos == 0) {
                                            //cameraoption();
                                            ClickImageFromCamera() ;


                                        } else if (pos == 1) {
                                            GetImageFromGallery();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                        alertbox.show();

                }
            });
        }
    public void ClickImageFromCamera() {

        CamIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "file" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        CamIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

        CamIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(CamIntent, 0);

    }
    public void GetImageFromGallery(){

        GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(GalIntent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 2);

    }




    private void allowpermission() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        1);

                checkpermission = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            ImageCropFunction();

        }
        else if (requestCode == 2) {

            if (data != null) {

                uri = data.getData();

                ImageCropFunction();

            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (data != null) {

                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

                Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");

                iv_dp.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }
    }

    public void ImageCropFunction() {

        // Image Crop Code
        try {
            CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

            CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");

            CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 180);
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 180);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
            CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "All set for your Profile Picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

    }
}


My XML is:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pro_image"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/dp_iv" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/smile_icon"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UserName"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/dob_icon"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date Of Birth"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="#AAAAAA"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fav_icon"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Favouries"
                android:id="@+id/fav_tv"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#AAAAAA"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/review_icon1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reviews"
                android:id="@+id/review_tv"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="#AAAAAA"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



Please help me in my issues over quality of images. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image-cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: how do i use libraries in my cde

Comment: The documentation for a library should include instructions for using it. Some libraries are also covered in other materials, like books and courses on Android app development.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include the library as local library project. Add this line to your build.gradle file

   ```
   compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
   ```
2. Add UCropActivity into your AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
    <activity
   android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
   ```
3. The uCrop configuration is created using the builder pattern.

   ```
     UCrop.of(sourceUri, destinationUri)
   .withAspectRatio(16, 9)
     .withMaxResultSize(maxWidth, maxHeight)
    .start(context);
   ```
4. Override onActivityResult method and handle uCrop result.

   ```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
       final Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
   } else if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
       final Throwable cropError = UCrop.getError(data);
   }
   }
   ```

---

Comment: My code is works fine but the images are in low quality how to set high resolution for it.. please help me